# Converting between int[ish] and double[ish] in asm.js

Tags: javascript, firefox, asm.js

If I need to, say, find the the integer part and the fractional part of a number within an asm.js module, how do I do it? None of the [standard operators](http://asmjs.org/spec/latest/#operators) convert between intish and doubleish types; even Math.floor returns a double, and its result can't be coerced to an int.

```
var floor = stdlib.Math.floor;

function(n) {
    n = +n;
    var a = 0;
    a = floor(n)|0; // fails: "Operands to bitwise ops must be intish"
    var b = 0.0;
    b = +(n-a); // would fail if compiler got to here
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Vyacheslav Egorov (twitter:@mraleph) says: use `~~` to coerce to an int. Special validation case: http://asmjs.org/spec/latest/#unaryexpression

```
a = ~~floor(n); // success!
```

Comment: Note that recent builds of FF (nightly channel) require `~~+floor(n)`, or sometimes `~~+floor(n)|0`.